# How to hide an ajax component on clicking it?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, conditional-rendering, ajax-update

I want to hide a richfaces ajax component when the component itself is clicked and render something else (an h:outputtext) in its place. Is this possible? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: Add rendering condition on component and re-render parent of it (+ other needed components). During event action change value for rendering condition of your component to false.

Answer (score -1):

You can update all the form

```
<rich:commandButton action="#{myBean.myAction}" reRender="formId" rendered="#{myBean.show}" />
```

Java code:

```
public void myAction() {
  show = !show;
}
```

Comment: Why updating the whole form? Why not just individual components?